# Powershell excute node.js script and capture output

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have some strange situation in Powershell. When I run:

```
PS> node.exe [PATH_TO_GRUNT]\grunt
```

I got full output (30-40 lines), but when I run:

```
PS> Write-Host(node.exe [PATH_TO_GRUNT]\grunt)
```

I gives me only one line. What is wrong with this? I tried to add --no-color, 2>&1 options but they don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -Separator flag:

```
PS> Write-Host(node.exe [PATH_TO_GRUNT]\grunt) -Separator `n
```

Comment: Does not work, still only one line is printed. Rest output is missing.

Comment: How do you write to the stdout? With console.out or process.stdout.write? If you use the latter you need to append '\n' after each line.